# cURL is already installed but still giving this error Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler

Tags: php, elasticsearch, curl, laravel-5, libcurl

I am trying to implement Elastic-search in my Laravel project but it is giving this error.

> Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler.

I double checked it for cURL and it is loaded inside my php also I was previously working on some other project and send many requests to different **API's** through cURL and it is working over there but inside laravel it gives me this error.

Why my xampp is doing so and how can I fix this issue Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` and check if cURL is indeed enabled for the project you're currently working on. There's a good chance there is a mixup in php configurations.

Comment: @apokryfos sir I already checked it is not enabled for this project but when I check it in other projects it is enabled I am confused with this behavior what can I do to make it work

Comment: `phpinfo` tells you which *php.ini* file is used. Make sure this project uses the same one (as well as the same php version) . If it does not then check your virtual host configuration in xampp

Comment: It's giving me this `http://prntscr.com/k4mpyt` and I am checking the same .ini file extension is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple instances of PHP installed. Check your Windows Enviroment Variables, to see from where PHP is running. Assuming your using Git, do a php -v in your terminal to see which php version is loaded and check if it corresponds with the php from your xampp. Or delete xampp and install it in a new folder like, webserver/xampp. Enables the php modules, restart your apache and mysql and check your phpinfo().

Comment: That do solve my problem cURL is now there but in order to use this I had to move all my projects to this new directory that is not right as I have many other libraries installed in the old xampp version with this solution I had to move each and everything to this new installation not a good idea for me as there are more than 90 projects in that old xampp version.

Comment: Got it. If you have over 90 projects that use a specific type of install in php/apache then its okay to keep them in the old install. On your machine you can install multiple instances of xampp. I have 3 xampp installs on my system for php 5.6, 7.0 and 7.2. All with own corresponding projects. 

You will evolve to more installs as your projects will get more complex, what if you will deliver a project in nginx with redis, or a MongoDB setup? You will need flexibility in your systems setup and dont think in terms of 1 setup for all projects. Reverse that, each project has its own setup.

Comment: forgot to mention I installed wamp and from their chooses PHP 7.1.6 and changed my PHP path from D:xampp to C:wamp now my D:/xampp is also running PHP from C:wamp this was the solution that worked for me.